# scroll can't be default prevented on touchmove event on iOS10

Tags: ios, scroll, touch, preventdefault, touchmove

On Safari 10, by defining a simple listener that prevents default a `touchmove` event within a scrollable element, the event is not default prevented as it does with Safari 9 and less (it also does in all major browsers).

This is reproducible here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGRxOv

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Take an element with scrollable content (overflow: scroll).
- Add an event listener on it for `touchmouve` event, and call `event.preventDefault()` in that event listener.

**Expected Results:**

The element should not be scrollable.

**Actual Results:**

The element is still scrollable on Safari 10.

**Version:**
iOS 10.0.2

Probably a webkit issue...I opened an [issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163207) on webkit bug tracker.

In the mean time, if anyone has a workaround (except prevent the `touchstart`), it would be great :)

I also tried to `return false` in the listener but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `{passive:false}` option to `addEventListener` ([explanation](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080)), and you also need to make sure you execute `e.preventDefault()` on `touchmove` **and** `touchstart`:

```js
window.addEventListener("touchstart", e=>e.preventDefault(), {passive:false});
window.addEventListener("touchmove", e=>e.preventDefault(), {passive:false});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for writing about this and raising an issue — it had me completely baffled!

Your codepen solution didn't seem to work for me, but I have since found another solution here: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/457

This is their solution:

```
window.addEventListener( 'touchmove', function() {})
```

Feels very hacky but has worked for my situation.

I hope this helps anyone else frustrated by this.